# sharing issue (weird description)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm having a weird experience with fb sharing. Whenever me or anyone share's my blog post, in the description area my ad codes are visible. This is hammering my adsense. I tried using facebook debugging tool and I got the following issues but I am unable to resolve it. Any help would be highly appreciable.

---

***Errors That Must Be Fixed: Body Meta: You have  tags ouside of your . This is either because your  was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.***

---

---

> **Warnings That Should Be Fixed: Inferred Property: The og:url property
>   should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from
>   other tags. Inferred Property: The og:title property should be
>   explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>   Inferred Property: The og:image property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Inferred
>   Property: The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even
>   if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the meta tags are in the wrong place but because you haven't given us a link to your site it's hard to be sure; they should be in the  section of the page. This would be causing the first error.

The second error refers to missing tags, but they might be 'missing' by virtue of not being in the correct place, so fix the first problem first

{edited after seeing your page}

The main error at the top is because you've a 
`<meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="{snipped}" />` tag outside the `<head></head>` section of your page.

The rest of the errors are because you haven't added any open graph tags at all - each page should have meta tags telling Facebook what title/description/image to use when sharing, as well as which app/user should be allowed to see the analytics and insights information for the shared links

For more information on how this works, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

If you want to just get up and running quickly, try the tool at Step 2 of the [Like Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to generate some sample tags

Comment: I am not getting how to fix it. My blog is http://techhogger.com. Please let me know where I should do what.

Comment: Thanks Igy,
But fb share was working fine with similar snippeds but how come suddenly it cause the error?

Comment: Maybe the validation has become stricter recently - if you have no tags at all Facebook will try to determine the name/description/etc from the page content, but maybe it's simply not trying any more because of the invalid meta tags outside the <head></head> section

Comment: I removed the alexa tags even though the problem is same. What should I do now?

Comment: Everything done. Removed meta tags. FB linker also does not show error now even though its not done. Still description comes as my ad codes. Kindly help

Comment: You still haven't added any open graph meta tags to that page

Comment: I did add. Though the same error. Lgy the same is happening with my another blog androidhogger.com Can you please let me fix it?

Comment: Now it does not show the proper description for my blog techhogger.com. I added following meta tags:
<meta property="og:title" content="TechHogger" />

<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://techhogger.com" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://techhogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/4-2.png" />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="TechHogger" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1197501578" />

But it doesnot extract image and description now.

Comment: You have multiple sets of tags on the same page, on http://'techhogger.com' I can see two of each tag, except for 'og:description' which is blank. 
The debug tool is picking those up too - please read the documentation and check your tags in the debug tool - i can't step through this every time you make a change

Comment: I even added description tag though I can see no effect? What should I do now?